# How to Add Column Values to Another Row Based on Some Criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have this table on MS SQL Server: Where I am trying to find the total numbers of active users per month of a specific year.

My database is a mess so some active users from December 2022 are being count as January and February 2023.

| Year | Month | Active_Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 123 |
| 2022 | 2 | 143 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022 | 12 | 100 |
| 2023 | 1 | 79 |
| 2023 | 2 | 3 |

How do I get the active users values from 2023 month 1 and 2 and add it to 2022 month 12 so I get a table like that:

| Year | Month | Active_Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 123 |
| 2022 | 2 | 143 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022 | 12 | 182 |

For any value greater than 2022 in the year column, the active users number should be added to active users in December 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 parts of script

```
SELECT
Year, Month, count(Active_users)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Year, Month
HAVING Year = 2022 AND month < 12

UNION

SELECT
Year, Month, count(Active_users)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Year
HAVING (Year = 2023) OR (Year = 2022 AND month = 12)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the sum of all active users as to the active users of month 12 as you get a scalar value

```
SELECT YEAR,Month 
  , CASE WHEN Month = 12 THEN Active_users + (SELECT SUM(Active_users) FROM  mytable WHERE YEAR = 2023 AND Month IN (1,2))
  ELSE Active_users END Active_users
FROM mytable
WHERe YEAR = 2022
```

| YEAR | Month | Active_users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 123 |
| 2022 | 2 | 143 |
| 2022 | 12 | 182 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bT9mG056)

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly! I should have thought about it.